# How to better write complex styles to an element via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I used to use jQuery before and lately I'm starting out with vanilla Javascript, I'm kinda new from here.

Given I have the following code, how can I construct it into much cleaner code? Please advice.

I have reasons for separating each of background styles instead of using `background` itself. I also have some reasons here why not to use CSS.

My implementation here is to set the settings thru `data` tag in HTML and uses javascript to render its style instead of using CSS.

```
const section_bg = document.querySelectorAll('.js-section-bg');

for (let i = 0; i < section_bg.length; i++) {
    var this_image = section_bg[i];

    let settings = {
        url: this_image.dataset.bgSrc,
        position: this_image.dataset.bgPosition,
        color: this_image.dataset.bgColor,
        size: this_image.dataset.bgSize,
        repeat: this_image.dataset.bgRepeat
    }

    this_image.style.backgroundRepeat = settings.repeat;
    this_image.style.backgroundSize = settings.size;
    this_image.style.backgroundColor = settings.color;
    this_image.style.backgroundPosition = settings.position;
    this_image.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + settings.url + "')";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ES6 template strings:

```
this_image.style.cssText = `background:${settings.color} url(${settings.url}) ${settings.position} / ${settings.size} ${settings.repeat}`;
```

You can, of course, not use ES6 template strings and concatenate the strings and variables manually.

---

[Background shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#Background_Properties)

Comment: thanks, this is a quick easy fix. Didn't know there's cssText that I can use.

Comment: Won't using cssTest remove any other inline style?

Comment: @NamanNehra - yes but you can easily write it as `+=` if you wish to add to already applied styles.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can write it like this:

```js
function $(sel) {
    return Object.assign(
        [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(sel), 0),
        {
            css: function (props) {
                this.forEach(function (el) {
                    Object.keys(props).forEach(function (k) {
                        el.style[k] = props[k];
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    );
}

$('div').css({
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    border: '3px solid blue'
});
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
```

Whether this makes sense is another question...

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.js-section-bg')).forEach(image => {
    const style = image.style,
          data = image.dataset;
    style.backgroundColor = data.bgColor;
    style.backgroundRepeat = data.bgRepeat;
    style.backgroundSize = data.bgSize;
    style.backgroundPosition = data.bgPosition;
    style.backgroundImage = `url('${data.bgSrc}')`;
});
```

Comment: Hey Naman, this is also a great fix, just I think vsync's has a shorter solution, I'm quite a Javascript noob, still learning. Didn't figure out I can use they way you do ;)